# Как определить, запущено ли на удаленном хосте приложение? - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, сокет, клиент-сервер, ip

Я пишу курсовую работу, в которой нужно написать игру по сети для двоих игроков.
У меня есть форма, в которую я прописываю IP-адрес удаленного компьютера и отправляю ему запрос. Мне неизвестно, запущено ли на этом компьютере мое приложение. Если запущено, то в нем должно появиться окно с информацией о попытке подключения. Если не запущено, то на моем компьютере должно появиться сообщение о том, что подключиться не удалось. Я использую сокеты для настройки соединения.

Вопрос: как определить, запущено ли на удаленном хосте приложение?

Comment: как обычно, отправляете запрос и ждете ответ-подтверждение. Ошибка или превышено время ожидания- приложение не запущено или проблемы с сетью.

Comment: Если  запрос на соединение  отвергнут, значит не запущено. Заголовк не совпадает по смыслу с вопросом в тексте. Почему?